# How can I use math.sin() in fillna in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

I tried to use the math.sin() function in fillna but I failed:

```
data['Sensor #1'].fillna(math.sin(data["Sample #"] * parameter), inplace = True)
```

Is there any way I can fix that?

Here's the error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-145-9199336c2860> in <module>()
     11 
     12 
---> 13 data['Sensor #1'].fillna(math.sin(data["Sample #"] * parameter), inplace = True)
     14 data['Sensor #2'].fillna(lambda r: r["Sample #"]**-parameter, inplace = True)
     15 # drop the row that has empty value(s) because we want to find anomalies

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in wrapper(self)
    115             return converter(self.iloc[0])
    116         raise TypeError("cannot convert the series to "
--> 117                         "{0}".format(str(converter)))
    118 
    119     return wrapper

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

Comment: what was failed? error message?

Comment: `math.sin` does not take an iterable here, it expects a single value. You need to use `np.sin`, which is vectorized

Comment: Hi Linna, welcome to SO.  Can you give a example of the data?  Preferably in a format where we can test it out for you.  e.g. a few rows using df.to_json.

Answer (score 2):

You're using a function that expects a scalar input.  `math.sin` is expecting a single value, i.e.:

```
>>> math.sin(1)
0.8414709848078965
```

You need a vectorized function to find the sine of each value in a Series, which in this case is provided by the `numpy` library:

```
>>> s = pd.Series([1,2,3])
>>> np.sin(s)
```

```
0    0.841471
1    0.909297
2    0.141120
dtype: float64
```

---

If you don't have `numpy` installed, you have two options:

- Run `pip install numpy`
- Use `pd.np.sin` instead

---

The rest of your code looks fine, here is a working example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6], 'c': [np.nan, 0.84, np.nan]})

   a  b     c
0  1  4   NaN
1  2  5  0.84
2  3  6   NaN

df.assign(c=df.c.fillna(np.sin(df.a)*df.b))
```

```
   a  b         c
0  1  4  3.365884
1  2  5  0.840000
2  3  6  0.846720
```